# What does "Вон оно чё" mean

Tags: перевод

I'm studying the Russian language and I try to watch lots of Russian television series. Recently I have watched the comedy show Наша Раша and in a specific sketch a character Иван Дулин many times repeats something like the words: "Вон оно чё" or "Вот оно чё". I have tried googling, but haven't found any answers. Does anyone have any ideas what those words might generally mean? When would a person use them? :)

Thank you for any help!

Here are some examples I found:

"Вот оно чего Михалыч! Выйдешь ты сейчас в цех, а меня нет, ни у станка, ни в столовой, даже в Челябинске меня нет."

"Вот оно че Михалыч, мне давеча сон про тебя приснился. Идешь ты значит по цеху в красных труселях, все по сторонам оглядываешься"

Comment: LOL, never expected to see a question about this series here. Just don't forget that *Челябинские мужики настолько суровы, что намазывают на хлеб нож*!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As @Riateche correctly pointed out, "чё" is a slang word for "что" - meaning "what".  "Вон" (in this context) means "that" or "there" (similarly, "вот" for "this" or "here").

There are two - somewhat different - meanings this phrase can take.

It is used to express an understanding of something at last, i.e. if somebody couldn't understand something for a while and then finally it dawned on them, it would be the right time to use it. The English equivalent would be *"That's what it is!"*

Consider this dialogue:

> – Не понимаю, нафига тебе нужна эта штуковина?
> – Эта штуковина - это ключ от замка на моём сарае.
> – Вон оно че!

with its English equivalent:

> – I don't get it, what the heck do you need this thing for?
> – This thing is the key from the lock on my shed.
> – That's what it is!

Here, the meaning of "вон/вот" is "that/this".  In its second meaning, "вон/вот" is used as "there/here" and means, literally, "here's what" or "here's the thing"/"here's the deal".  It would be used to express a level of certainty or authority at the start of a speech, for example:

> Вот оно чего Михалыч! Выйдешь ты сейчас в цех, а меня нет, ни у станка, ни в столовой, даже в Челябинске меня нет.
>
> Here's the deal, Mikhalych!  You'll come out now onto the machine floor - and I'm not there, not near the workbench, not in the canteen, not even in Chelyabinks.

or

> Вот оно че Михалыч, мне давеча сон про тебя приснился. Идешь ты значит по цеху в красных труселях, все по сторонам оглядываешься
>
> Here's what [it is], Mikhalych, I saw a dream about you the other day. You're walking along the machine floor in your red underpants and looking around.

Comment: "чё" is an informal version for "чего", not "что".

Comment: @smsrecv Not true.  Consider phrase _чё это такое?_

Comment: @AleksG _чё это такое?_ = _чего это такое?_ But you can't replace _что_ with _чё_ in the sentence _Он сказал, что он вернётся_. Because as I said _чё_ does not mean _что_, it means _чего_ and therefore cannot be used as conjunction

Comment: _чё_ means exactly _что_ - but it can't be used as a substitute for it in all cases.  I can't think of an example where _чё_ means clear _чего_ - can you give one?

Comment: @smsrecv I posted a [separate question](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2437/meaning-of-%D1%87%D1%91-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-or-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE) to confirm this.

Comment: @AleksG _чё_ is the result of dropping _-ег-_ from _чего_

Answer (score 4):

"чё" is an informal version of "что". "Вот <вон> оно что" usually means expression of surprising.  See [dictionary page](http://phraseologiya.academic.ru/168/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82_%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE_%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE!) for definition and examples.