# Meaning of чё - что or чего?

Tags: значения, сленг

This question was born from the discussion in comments under [this answer](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/2397/97).

*Чё* is a slang/colloquial word, but does it mean *что* or *чего*?  I believe that it's the equivalent of *что*, although it can't be substituted in all cases - and I used this in my answer to the linked question.  However another user stated that I was wrong and that the correct meaning is *чего*.

So, which meaning is correct?

**UPDATE:** It was suggested to me that it can mean both, e.g.

> Чё тебе надо?
> Что тебе надо?
> Чего тебе надо?

However in this case, I'd say that in the last example (*чего тебе надо*), *чего* is in itself a colloquial form of *что*, hence it can't be argued to be the meaning of *чё*.

Comment: @v'-5o-1's73- (1) Please refrain from using profanities on this site. (2) _Чего ты хочешь?_ is a colloquial version of _что ты хочешь?_ - thus the meaning behind _чё_ is actually _что_, and not _чего_, making your comment factually incorrect.

Comment: First, you'd better prove your point that "чего" is a colloquial. Second, it would be nice if you give a consistent definition of what colloquial is and what it is not. Until then I will keep my downvote. http://phraseology.academic.ru/3926/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_(%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE)_%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0_%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82

Comment: @v'-5o-1's73- I did requested the reason for the downvote, not for it to be rescinded - and I appreciate your reason. As for what "colloquial" means... In my view, it's any usage that's generally accepted yet not grammatically correct.

Comment: Neither "generally accepted" nor "in my view" can be used to define colloquial. Also you didn't prove it's grammatically incorrect. Thus you cannot reason about it being colloquial. Unless you think that your personal view matters a lot. If this is the way you write your programs, then I feel bad for your customers.

Comment: @v'-5o-1's73- I'm not sure why you feel inclined to make personal attacks - it doesn't score you any points, only makes you look desperate.

Comment: God forbid, I didn't attack you yet, my friend. All I am saying your statements are groundless and you don't bother to support them.

Comment: Чё is что; however, in colloquial speech что is sometimes substituted for чего. You can say что тебе надо and it will not sound obviously broken.

Answer (score 8):

There are some sentences in which `чё` cannot be substituted for `чего`, have a look:

> Чё у тебя в карманах?
>
> Чё там случилось?

In such sentences `чё` is the subject, which can be in the Genetive case only in negative sentences, like `Ивана там не было.` or as a part of a quantitative phrase, like `много людей`, `три рубля`, `сколько зайцев`, etc.

And this:

> Не за что. (Cannot be *Не за чё.)

And `Ни за что!`

Also, there are some sentences in which `чего` cannot be substituted for `чё`:

> С чего будем прыгать, с моста или с причала? (Not *с чё)
>
> С чего бы это? (Not *с чё)
>
> От чего ты отталкивался? (Not *от чё)
>
> Без чего не вытащишь и рыбку из пруда? (Not *без чё)

To sum it up, it looks like `чё` is a colloquial form of `что`.

Comment: Your first two examples are plain wrong («Чего у тебя в карманах?»/«Чего там случилось?» are perfectly correct in informal spoken speech), so it actually lokks like *чё* is an even more colloquial substitute for *чего* when it works as a colloquial substitute of "что" but not in their other uses. I could not come up with any example where you can use "чё" but cannot use "чего".

Comment: @Shady_arc, one example of a phrase that I cannot push myself saying with _чего_ is _«а на чё мы жить-то будем?»_. But  I am not an expert in the colloquial syntax and may be wrong.

Comment: @J-mster You cannot use "чего" either in "А на *чё* мы жить-то будем". Only "что" is possible here.

Comment: @Shady_arc, do you mean that neither «чё» or «чего» cannot be used with «на»? Might be not. For me «чо» is quite ok in this context, but I have no independent evidence to support it.

Comment: @J-mster Aaah! You meant that "На чё мы жить-то будем?" sounds OK to you? I should have really been more careful when reading.

Comment: OK, now it seems even more complicated. I'd probably not use "на чё", ever, but "чего" sounds even more wrong. Apparently, "чё" can replace "что" in Accusative after prepositions while "чего" rarely can. However, I am not sure about the exact list of prepositions. If you take *о, под, по, за, про, на, в, через, с, сквозь* with Accusative, they do not seem all equally good for such use.

Comment: @Shady_arc - They do.

Comment: @Shady_arc "А на чего мы жить-то будем" sounds OK

Comment: @smsrecv I would say, "а на чего мы жить-то будем" sounds as wrong as "а на чё мы жить-то будем", although both plausible. So it's not a convincing counter-example.

Comment: @il--ya sounds absolutely normal

Answer (score 6):

**чё** is the result of the omission of the -**ег**- syllable in **чего**. This is called [Elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision) in phonetics. So **чё** is just a shortened form of **чего**

*[чево́]* >> *[чео́]* >> *[чо]* (spelled as *чё*)

This same thing happens with *сегодня* becoming *сёдня*

Comment: In sentences like _чё тебе надо?_ и _это чё такое?_ word _чё_ is clearly a substitute for _что_, because grammatically correct versions of these sentences are _что тебе надо?_ and _это что такое?_.

Comment: @AleksG *Чего* as a pronoun is widely used instead of *что*. In your examples *чё* is a substitute for *чего*: *Чего тебе надо? Это чего такое?*. And I repeat *чё* and *чего* is the same word. Just like *сегодня* = *сёдня*. It is the result of the omission of the *ег* syllable.

Comment: You've got a typo in "Elision".

Comment: @AleksG Nothing about "Чё те надо" is grammatical. They'd be saying чего if anything

Comment: It can also mean "Что? Что ты сказал?" (What did you say?). So in this case "чё" is reduction from "что".

Comment: @ValentinShergin Где логика-то? То что "чё ты сказал" по смыслу равно "что ты сказал" еще не значит, что "чё" образовалось от "что". Потому что точно так это равно "чего ты сказал". То есть у тебя есть 2 одинаковых по смыслу варианта 1)"что ты сказал" и 2)"чего ты сказал". Теперь докажи что "чё ты сказал" образовалось от 1) а не от 2). "Че" не равно "что" хотя бы потому что ты не можешь заменить "что" на "че" везде. Например ты не можешь сказать "я знаю чё он придет" вместо "я знаю что он придет". "че" - это результат стяжения в быстрой речи слова "чего". "Чево" >> "чео" >> "чо" (пишем "чё").

Answer (score 4):

Using genitive/partitive as a subject is a perfectly normal thing in a lot of languages: Czech language's *co* "what" in nominative stems from an ancient genitive case as well (from *čьso*). Even Proto-Indoeuropean's *kwid* suspiciously looks like an ablative form (~ partitive-like).

So, чё does stem from чего, but it can be thought of as a rightful variation of что in the modern language (with its own quirks).

Answer (score 2):

Чё (or чо) can be used instead of both что and чего  (both as subject and object). But in Southern Russia and Ukraine что is mostly replaced by шо, чего is not replaced in Russian, but is чого in Ukrainian (pronounced not чиво, чево or чаво but choho).

Answer (score 1):

Это может быть как чего, так и что. В зависимости от контекста. Вариант "Чего тебе надо?" для меня, как носителя языка звучит как более вежливый вариант, а никак не разговорным. Оба грамматически корректные. Вообще сама по себе конструкция, что с чё или с полным вариантом звучит грубо и невежливо.

Comment: Хорошее замечание про регистр. Сразу вспоминается "Чего тебе надобно, старче?"